# git svn fails with fatal error

Tags: svn, git

While moving our svn repository to git I got the following error message:

```
$ git svn clone svn://abraham/eeschweiz -s
Initialized empty Git repository in /cygdrive/c/Users/Ernst/Temp/svn2git/eeschweiz/.git/
Using higher level of URL: svn://abraham/eeschweiz => svn://abraham
  0 [main] perl 3836 C:\cygwin\bin\perl.exe: *** fatal error - unable to remap \\?\C:\cygwin\lib\sasl2\cygsasldb-2.dll to same address as parent: 0x9D0000 != 0xA20000
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
0088B678  6102796B  (0088B678, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
0088B968  6102796B  (6117EC60, 00008000, 00000000, 61180977)
0088C998  61004F1B  (611A7FAC, 6124B6A4, 009D0000, 00A20000)
End of stack trace
  0 [main] perl 6864 fork: child 3836 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
fork failed: Resource temporarily unavailable at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10/Git.pm line 462.
```

I was able to migrate ~10 folders under svn://abraham without any problems. After getting this error message I can't clone any of the folders, not even the ones which worked before.
The command is executed in cygwin on Win7 64.

Any ideas about what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seams to be a cygwin problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014554/git-svn-error-under-cygwin